# panic() stacktrace does not show function parameters

Tags: go

In the below code:

```golang
package main
    
func main() {
    example(make([]string, 2, 4), "hello", 10)
}
    
func example(slice []string, str string, i int) {
    panic("Want stack trace")
}
```

---

6 words are being used to store data and pass to function `example`.

- 3 words for `slice` header
- 2 words for `str` string
- one word for `i` integer

---

Expected stack trace:

```
goroutine 1 [running]:
main.example(0xc000042748, 0x2, 0x4, 0x106abae, 0x5, 0xa)
    stack_trace/example1/example1.go:13 +0x39
main.main()
    stack_trace/example1/example1.go:8 +0x72
    
// Declaration
main.example(slice []string, str string, i int)
    
// Call
make([]string, 2, 4), "hello", 10
    
// Values (0xc000042748, 0x2, 0x4, 0x106abae, 0x5, 0xa)
Slice Value:   0xc000042748, 0x2, 0x4
String Value:  0x106abae, 0x5
Integer Value: 0xa
```

---

Actual stack trace:

```
panic: Want stack trace
    
goroutine 1 [running]:
main.example(...)
        /home/../Main.go:8
main.main()
        /home/../Main.go:4 +0x39
exit status 2
```

---

```
$ go version
go version go1.14.3 linux/amd64
```

---

Why does the stacktrace generated from `panic()` not show those 6 words?

Comment: Do stacktraces typically include the values of variables? I have not seen that before. If you would like to implement this yourself, you can capture the stack with https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/debug/#Stack and then print the values as well.

Comment: I think you are looking for runtime.SetTraceback()

Answer (score 6):

Go is showing `main.example(...)` because the **function is inlined by the compiler** and doesn't exist as a function anymore, it's been embedded in `main()` (details of the printing logic are in [traceback.go](https://golang.org/src/runtime/traceback.go?#L408)).

You can tell the compiler **not to inline the function** by using the `go:noinline` [compiler directive](https://golang.org/cmd/compile/#hdr-Compiler_Directives):

```golang
//go:noinline
func example(slice []string, str string, i int) {
  panic("Want stack trace")
}
```

With inlining disabled, the default traceback output shows `main.example` and its parameters:

```
panic: Want stack trace

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.example(0xc000046738, 0x2, 0x4, 0x473f27, 0x5, 0xa)
    /home/me/stuff/src/github.com/me/testing/panic/main.go:9 +0x39
main.main()
    /home/me/stuff/src/github.com/me/testing/panic/main.go:4 +0x72
```

Note that `make` does not appear in the stack trace, nor can it: it has returned before `panic` is ever reached.

**A word of advice**: `go:noinline` is used here to show why the stack trace does not contain the function arguments. One should generally not force compiler optimization decisions unless debugging the compiler or dealing with runtime functions that need it.

Comment: What does "function is inlined by the compiler" mean?

Comment: Expected stack trace also has `make()` call. Is this also considered inline? Actual stacktrace does not show that.

Comment: Why would `make` be there? It's not calling `panic`, it's called and has returned before `panic`.