# Go prints different function name from program counters returned from runtime.Callers() if I use errors package

Tags: go, debugging, runtime, callstack

**code1:**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/pkg/errors"
    "runtime"
)

func main() {
    ptrs, _ := Test1("arg1", "arg2")
    for _, pc := range *ptrs {
        f := runtime.FuncForPC(pc)
        if f == nil {
            continue
        }
        filename, line := f.FileLine(pc)
        fmt.Printf("func name: %s, entry: %x, filename: %s, line: %d\n", f.Name(), f.Entry(), filename, line)
    }
}

func Test0(args ...interface{}) *[]uintptr {
    const depth = 32
    var pcs [depth]uintptr
    n := runtime.Callers(0, pcs[:])
    st := pcs[0:n]
    return &st
}

func Test1(args ...interface{}) (*[]uintptr, error) {
    return Test0(args...), errors.New("Test")
}
```

**code2:**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
)

func main() {
    ptrs, _ := Test1("arg1", "arg2")
    for _, pc := range *ptrs {
        f := runtime.FuncForPC(pc)
        if f == nil {
            continue
        }
        filename, line := f.FileLine(pc)
        fmt.Printf("func name: %s, entry: %x, filename: %s, line: %d\n", f.Name(), f.Entry(), filename, line)
    }
}

func Test0(args ...interface{}) *[]uintptr {
    const depth = 32
    var pcs [depth]uintptr
    n := runtime.Callers(0, pcs[:])
    st := pcs[0:n]
    return &st
}

func Test1(args ...interface{}) (*[]uintptr, error) {
    return Test0(args...), nil//, errors.New("Test")
}
```

The only different part is returning error value of `Test1()`. In the **code1** it returns `erors.New("Test")`, in the **code2** it returns `nil`. In the FOR loop of `main` function, the program prints function name, the results are different:

**result of code1:**

```
func name: runtime.Callers, entry: 6a20c0, filename: C:/Program Files/Go/src/runtime/extern.go, line: 247
func name: runtime.Callers, entry: 6a20c0, filename: C:/Program Files/Go/src/runtime/extern.go, line: 247
func name: main.Test1, entry: 6a2180, filename: D:/develop/go-testbed/cmd/slicetest/slicetest.go, line: 30
func name: main.main, entry: 6a1ea0, filename: D:/develop/go-testbed/cmd/slicetest/slicetest.go, line: 11
func name: runtime.main, entry: 6476a0, filename: C:/Program Files/Go/src/runtime/proc.go, line: 259
func name: runtime.goexit, entry: 66eee0, filename: C:/Program Files/Go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s, line: 1595
```

**result of code2**

```
func name: runtime.Callers, entry: b30020, filename: C:/Program Files/Go/src/runtime/extern.go, line: 247
func name: runtime.Callers, entry: b30020, filename: C:/Program Files/Go/src/runtime/extern.go, line: 247
func name: main.main, entry: b2fe00, filename: D:/develop/go-testbed/cmd/slicetest/slicetest.go, line: 10
func name: main.main, entry: b2fe00, filename: D:/develop/go-testbed/cmd/slicetest/slicetest.go, line: 9
func name: runtime.main, entry: ad6fc0, filename: C:/Program Files/Go/src/runtime/proc.go, line: 259
func name: runtime.goexit, entry: afe580, filename: C:/Program Files/Go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s, line: 1595
```

As you see, **code1** printed the correct function name, `main.Test1` but **code2** didn't.
I read [runtime.Callers print different program counters depending on where its run from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64135896/runtime-callers-print-different-program-counters-depending-on-where-its-run-from) which recommands to use `runtime.CallersFrames()` but I thinks it's not the problem because both **code1** and **code2** do not use it. I also see the `errors.New()` function but I didn't find something special. It creates callstack by `caller()` function which is almost same as `Test0()` in my code -- actually, I copied the contents of `Test0()` from `caller()`.

Can someone tell me which causes the difference?

Go version: go1.19 windows/amd64

OS: windonws 11

version of `github.com/pkg/errors`: v0.9.1

Both of codes print the same result with `main.Test1` if I run them in debug mode of Goland IDE.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation of runtime.Callers

> To translate these PCs into symbolic information such as function names and line numbers, **use CallersFrames**. CallersFrames accounts for inlined functions and adjusts the return program counters into call program counters. **Iterating over the returned slice of PCs directly is discouraged**, as is using FuncForPC on any of the returned PCs, since these cannot account for inlining or return program counter adjustment.

(emph mine)
You must not try to interpret the result of runtime.Callers yourself as you cannot do it properly. Your flawed attempt clearly demonsrates that the documentation is right.

This has literally *nothing* to do with github.com/pkg/errors (which is unmaintained and superseeded by new stuff in package errors anyway). It is a result of the compiler optimizing your code (differently while debugging).

Rule of thumb: Read the documentation of the functions you use and do what the documentation tells you. This is an instance of "Sometimes 3 month in the lab can spare you 6 hours in the library".

Comment: Thank you. As I mentioned, I knew the `CallersFrames()` would solve my problem. What I really want to know is, WHY the results are different. I expected the same result, because the call chain, `errors.New(...) -> errors.callers() -> runtime.Callers()` does not include `CallersFrames()`, and my codes do nothing with the error. Reading document is important but... it is also important that the programs show same result for the same code in most cases. In my question, two codes are SAME except the part returning error so they should print same logs for function name.

Comment: @Hodol Your code gets rewritten differently depending on the code (presence of errors.New) and whether it's being debuged or not. There is nothing to see here. The compiler is free to do so. There is no hidden why, just one function gets optimised differently than a different one.

Comment: O.K. I understand that the `errors` package can affect on the behavior of compiler. Thanks.